# Pending Transaction / Transaction not found

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions

This is one of the issues I face in almost any DAPP I build on ethereum. Transactions are not found on etherscan or any block exlorer.

Currently, I have a web wallet running. As a part of application, people can withdraw their ERC_20 tokens from wallet which in a transaction of Token from admin account to user's account.

Currently, more than 100 transactions send in last 2 day are in pending. When I check tx on etherscan all of them are **not found**.

**What are the reasons for a transaction not showing up to other nodes.**

The reasons I know:
There is huge traffic in the network, which indeed is not the case here. It may take some time to reach to other nodes but this should not take 2 days.

When I check the pending txs on my geth node, I can see all transactions in pending state. I supplied enough gas 90000 and sufficient gas price 110-11 GWei for each tx. So transactions were perfect from my end. **Is there any full-proof solution to avoid this issue?**

This happens in most of applications with a moderate amount of users transacting. Transactions are pending/lost. How can one be sure to avoid these issues or atleast minimize, more than 100 pending transactions are not avoidable.

**EDIT 1:**

I found the reason of the pending transactions. The first pending transaction had gas price of 4 GWei, which didn't go through and since that tx is pending all the transaction following that tx was pending no matter if the next txs were provided higher gas.

I used the default gas price supplied by `eth.gasPrice`. So it gave me 4 GWEI, I send a tx and all are pending afterwards. I even raised issue on github [web3.eth.gasPrice is returning incorrect value](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1230). But this is not resolved even after 6 months.

I found the reason but don't have any solution (a long term working solution).

- How the big applications handle this gas price issue?
- Why [eth.gassttation](https://ethgasstation.info/) provided more accurate value than
  `eth.gasPrice`?
- Even if I assume gas price is low and tx is pending, why it's not on other nodes like etherscan or ethercamp or  even my other geth instance
- What exactly happens if the transaction is wiped out from my geth mem as well?

Comment: are all the transactions which are not showing up coming after one another? or are there a few going through here and there in-between?

Comment: They are one after the other.